# undefined en un evento React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

Tengo un problema y es que al momento de darle click a un  el `e.target.name` y el `e.target.value` llega
`undefined : undefined`

Esta es la funcion

```
handleChange = e => {
 
  this.setState({  
    [e.target.name] :e.target.value
  })
}
```

este es el div que le mando los parametros

```
render(){
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {
            this.state.preguntaYRespuestas.map((pregunta)=>(
              <div>
                <div name={pregunta.id} value={pregunta.pregunta} key={pregunta.id} onClick={this.handleChange}>{pregunta.pregunta}</div>
                <div>
                    {
                        pregunta.respuestas.map((respuesta)=>(
                            <div onClick={this.handleChange} name={`${pregunta.id}_${respuesta.id}`} value={respuesta.opcion} key={`${pregunta.id}_${respuesta.id}`}>{respuesta.opcion}</div>    
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
        }
</div>
```

LLega `undefined : undefined` al momento de darle click

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Sebas, qué datos se imprimen pantalla en el `name` y `value` de los elementos?, tal vez no están imprimiendo correctamente. También está dando "click" a un div, trate de cambiarlo a un <button type="button"></button>.

Comment: agrega todo el codigo como haces el bind del evento en el componente

Comment: Cambie el div por ui imput y me srivio!